# Ошибка синтаксиса Python в задаче на циклы?

Tags: python

Здравствуйте уважаемые участники этого форума!
Помогите пожалуйста со следующим заданием:

Задание: Бегун готовится к соревнованиям. Сейчас он может пробежать start километров, а на соревнованиях ему нужно будет пробежать goal километров. До соревнования осталось days дней. Во время подготовки к соревнованиям спортсмен может увеличивать дистанцию, которую он пробегает, не больше, чем на 10% в день. В день соревнования тренироваться нельзя.
Напишите программу, которая рассчитывает, успеет ли спортсмен подготовиться к соревнованиям? Выведите True, если успеет и False, если не успеет.

Я написал следующий код этой программы:

```
class Runner(object):
 
   def eval(self, string):
 
     start = float(input())
     goal = float(input())
     days = int(input())
     while start < goal: 
       start = start*1.1 
       days = days - 1
     if days >= 1:
       print("TRUE")
     else:
       print("FALSE")
     return value
   def loop(self):
     line = input()
     value = self.eval(line)
     print(value)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   calc = Runner()
   calc.loop()
```

Но, когда я пытаюсь запустить эту программу, у меня выходит ошибка "invalid syntax".
Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить эту ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

```py
days = 5
start = 800
goal = 1200
print(start * (1.1 ** (days - 1)) >= goal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю в чем проблема, но можно попробовать считать дни а не км в while.
То есть так:

```
while days > 0:
start = start*1.1
days -= 1
```

Так вроде должно заработать

Comment: Так не заработает. Проверьте отступы